# Can IPSEC using AH be used in Transport Mode if a machine is behind NAT firewall?

Tags: security, networking, firewall, privacy, ipsec

Can IPSEC using AH be used in Transport Mode if a machine is behind NAT firewall? Please help me answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, through NAT-Traversal and UDP-Encapsulation, but not easily, and with some important drawbacks.

Reference: http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-3947.txt

Drawbacks: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3715#section-2.2

Better use tunnel mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.